# How do I remove the connector covers on thermostat wires?

Tags: heating

[image]

How do i go about removing the plastic tabs without damaging or cutting the wires? We live in a down stairs apartment and get no heat cause they control it and all I have to do is remove these tabs so I can control the heat, it gets to cold down here for my 10 month old son.

Comment: Did somebody, *like,* tell you that?  Or do you actually know how to install a thermostat?  If not, grab a book, it's not /that/ hard and knowledge is power.  But if you do stuff like that, you have a good chance of breaking the upstairs neighbor's heat, so you *really* need to know what you're doing.  Also, have the assent of the landlord, because any landlord will have you hauled out by the cops if you endanger the building, i.e. cut off heat during a freeze.  Can you plug in an electric heater? The oil "radiator" style ones are quite safe.

Comment: It's even colder outside, which is where you'll be once you either, a., call the city and complain about the heating situation in your illegal apartment, or b., are asked to leave by your landlord.

Comment: Have you tried talking to your landlord about the situation? It seems that this is a problem *he* created, not you, so its on him to fix.

Comment: It may be as simple as adjusting some restrictors to give more flow to your apartment. Setting of  thermostats is a very common thing for people to have to negotiate.

Comment: What kind of heating system? Hot water or forced air? Both usually have ways to adjust for more heat up or down. Altering the thermostat will not fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Those aren't covers. They are permanently crimped connectors, like wire nuts but cheaper and faster. To do work on those wires you'd normally just cut them off and strip the wires fresh.

I'd take Harper's advice though and proceed with extreme caution. It sounds like you're not familiar with thermostat wiring and you can get yourself into real trouble.